# Design advice JMS or Webservices

Tags: web-services, jms

I need to send some messages to other systems say 10 other systems (size 50 KB XML) and all
the others are JAVA based systems which is a good alternative ?JMS or WEBServices ?
What are the other alternatives?

Comment: Could you add a few more details on requirements?  Synchronous or asynchronous?  Within the DMZ or external?  Pull or push? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can have webservices over jms. Webservice is in another layer. If what you mean is to communicate xml between systems, for me the easiest is HTTP. Here there  is an interesting blog that can help you:

http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/the-soa-blog/web-services-http-vs-jms-19110

Answer (score 0):

In my view JMS offers better features and control in case of a distributed system as yours. You can have transactions and have better failure handling.